# Replicate react-admin Save Button

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am using `react-admin` framework. I am trying to replicate the `SaveButton` so I can put this button to my custom `Actions` component and show that button on different parts of my web application. I have managed to create my custom `Actions` but when clicking on the button, it is not doing anything. This is docs to the button:

https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/button/SaveButton.tsx

My code so far:

```
const EditActions = ({ basePath, data, redirect }) =>
(
    <CardActions>
        <ShowButton basePath={basePath} record={data} />
        <SaveButton submitOnEnter={false} redirect={redirect} />
    </CardActions>
);
```

And I call my actions like this:

```
<EditView actions={<EditActions />} {...props} />
```

Any ideas how can I replicate the `SaveButton` and its save action?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [SaveButton](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/52a4ca810eebb1eea25e900392432b14024f8097/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/button/SaveButton.tsx#L23-L38) requires quite a few things to be passed as props, like `handleSubmit/handleSubmitWithRedirect`

The Component passed in `EditView` `actions` prop doesn't seem to receive any of these properties 
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/94b0828558ed783dab000ecbc03f8a3e0447111c/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/detail/Edit.js#L119-L127

Have you tried passing them down via `EditActions`?

```
const EditActions = ({ basePath, data, redirect, ...props }) =>
(
    <CardActions>
        <ShowButton basePath={basePath} record={data} />
        <SaveButton submitOnEnter={false} redirect={redirect} {...props} />
    </CardActions>
);

....

<EditView actions={<EditActions {...props} />} {...props} />
```

Comment: I did, but with no luck. Console returns `Uncaught TypeError: handleSubmitWithRedirect is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

The SaveButton needs to be a form toolbar override and not an actions override of the EditView. The form toolbar will have a different set of props than the Edit View. You'll have to be creative about styling to get this toolbar up at the top of the EditView.

From the docs:

```
const PostEditToolbar = props => (
    <Toolbar {...props} >
        <SaveButton />
    </Toolbar>
);

export const PostEdit = (props) => (
    <Edit {...props}>
        <SimpleForm toolbar={<PostEditToolbar />}>
            // ...
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```